# Why is Bootstrap 5 keyframe going to top of button?

Tags: css, css-animations, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I've played with this for a while and am looking for some help. Just a basic Bootstrap 5 dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

using the following css:

```
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .dropdown-menu {
        animation-duration: 0.4s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
        animation-name: slideIn;
      }
    }

    @keyframes slideIn {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        transform: translateY(0rem);
        opacity: 1;
      }

      0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: transform;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
      }

      0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

results in the dropdown sliding up to completely cover the dropdown button. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rglLE.png)

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a benefit of using keyframes to animate vs just css transitions?